# Linked images not being displayed on HTML when opened outside of Atom

Tags: javascript, html, ip, atom-editor, live-streaming

This is my first post here, so I apologise if there's anything wrong with the format I'm writing. I've been developing a very simple page for the past few days for a html university project about security cameras w/ atom and bulma, had a few struggles linking them onto the html because even though all the security cameras are live video, for some reason, the code would only display it if it was written within an image code. 
The code basically randomizes a number within an array of 100+ objects and chooses 2 different ones, they're then displayed side by side, the page refreshes itself every 60 second, showing another set of 2 images.
The problem is, after I finished the entire thing, working perfectly on atom-live-server, I saved it and tried to open directly with the browser, which is how my professor is going to open, but there the media isn't displayed and there's only an icon. Same thing with trying to upload it onto a website. All the security camera links come from open IPs, are http and aren't protected, but I could open all of them on the browser when done directly outside the code and also on atom-live-server.

Here's what the JS part is like:

```
  script type="text/javascript"

  window.onload = choosePic;

  var myPix = new Array
  ("//180.23.155.164:8082/-wvhttp-01-/GetOneShot?&frame_count=1000000000#.XuE-YLJZhYI.link",
  "//180.220.70.194:1024/-wvhttp-01-/GetOneShot?&frame_count=1000000000#.XujHZZ-5jOU.link",
  "//107.85.194.33:8081/-wvhttp-01-/GetOneShot?&frame_count=1000000000#.XujTCpm4q4M.link",
  "//5.11.180.152:8080/-wvhttp-01-/GetOneShot?&frame_count=1000000000#.XujSfteGlxY.link"
 //there's a lot of links so I'll spare you all of that
);

  function choosePic() {
          var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random()* myPix.length);
          var randomNum2 = Math.round(Math.random()* myPix.length);
          while (randomNum === randomNum2) {
           randomNum2 = Math.round(Math.random()*myPix.length);


       document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[randomNum];
       document.getElementById("myPicture2").src = myPix[randomNum2];

   }
```

and this is the code in the body:

```
<body>
   <section class="hero is-fullheight has-background-black">
     <div class="hero-body">
       <div class="container">
         <!--<p href="" class="title is-size-4 has-text-white center">Peek</p>!-->
         <figure class="center">
          <img src="" width="640" height="480" id="myPicture">
          <img src="" width="640" height="480" id="myPicture2">
         </figure>
       </div>
     </div>
   </section>

  </body>
```

I think it probably has to do with the format of the links, but I'm not sure. I appreciate any help, I'm very new to coding and html in general. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your browser's developer console say? Are there any errors?

Comment: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND". But if I actually type the link of the camera directly on the browser, it opens. One of the tutorials I read instructed to remove the http:// part when writing the array, do you think it may have something to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly remove `src=` attributes from your `<img>`s, secondly use `http://...` in your camera URL addresses because they are not secured.

There is one camera feed - the one with a road and cars - that one sometimes fails to load becuase of the server issues. Other camera resources are fine.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  
  // Camera sources - must hasve 'http' if not secured
  var myPix = new Array(
    "http://180.23.155.164:8082/-wvhttp-01-/GetOneShot?&frame_count=1000000000#.XuE-YLJZhYI.link",
    "http://180.220.70.194:1024/-wvhttp-01-/GetOneShot?&frame_count=1000000000#.XujHZZ-5jOU.link",
    "http://107.85.194.33:8081/-wvhttp-01-/GetOneShot?&frame_count=1000000000#.XujTCpm4q4M.link",
    "http://5.11.180.152:8080/-wvhttp-01-/GetOneShot?&frame_count=1000000000#.XujSfteGlxY.link"
  );

  function choosePic() {
    var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * myPix.length);
    var randomNum2;

    // Keep generating randomNum2 if randomNum equals randomNum2
    do {
      randomNum2 = Math.round(Math.random() * myPix.length)
    } while(randomNum === randomNum2);

    document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[randomNum];
    document.getElementById("myPicture2").src = myPix[randomNum2];
  }

  // First loading of camera resources
  choosePic();

  // Execute choosePic() every 60000ms = 60s 
  setInterval(choosePic, 60000);
});
```

```html
<section class="hero is-fullheight has-background-black">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container">
      <!--<p href="" class="title is-size-4 has-text-white center">Peek</p>!-->
      <figure class="center">
        <img width="640" height="480" id="myPicture">
        <img width="640" height="480" id="myPicture2">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It worked quite well! Thanks! I had to adjust the sizes a little bit but it's online. Oh, also what you said regarding the images that don't load because of the server made me wonder if theres a way to code to randomize a new image if the chosen one isn't able to load

Comment: It was well recieved, thank you once again! But sometimes some cameras get unavailable because of connection issues or hardware issues, so I'm still wondering whether there'd be a way for the code to "test" the image before displaying to avoid broken links